# How can I wait for screen to be resized before executing script using Selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I currently have a problem at this part of my code:

```
webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
webDriver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

The problem is that I want my screen to resize before the script executes and performs a scroll, and the sleep command helps me to achieve that. But if I remove it, the scrolling sometimes occurs before the screen is resized. I've tried replacing the sleep with an ExpectedCondition check:

```
private boolean waitForScreenToResize(final int HEIGHT) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 1);

    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> screenResized = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            return webDriver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() == HEIGHT;
        }
    };

    return wait.until(screenResized);
}

webDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
waitForScreenToResize(height);
webDriver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

I thought this would work but the problem still remains. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: Forgot to mention that I want to remove the sleep and replace it with a logical way to check that the screen has resized.

Comment: increase timeOut to 5 seconds in new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 1); and try. I suspect 1 second is not sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to wait for the `scrollHeight` to change if the size of the document change when the window is resized :

```
String JS_GET_SCROLL_HEIGHT = "return Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight) | 0;";
String JS_SCROLL_BOTTOM = "window.scroll(0, -1 >>> 1);";

// get the current scroll height
Object scrollHeight = driver.executeScript(JS_GET_SCROLL_HEIGHT);

// set the size of the window
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));

// wait for the scroll height to change
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  .until(drv -> !drv.executeScript(JS_GET_SCROLL_HEIGHT).equals(scrollHeight));

// scroll to the bottom
driver.executeScript(JS_SCROLL_BOTTOM);
```

If not, you could also try to wait for the `innerHeight` to change :

```
String JS_GET_INNER_HEIGHT = "return window.innerHeight | 0;";
String JS_SCROLL_BOTTOM = "window.scroll(0, -1 >>> 1);";

// get the current scroll height
Object innerHeight = driver.executeScript(JS_GET_INNER_HEIGHT);

// set the size of the window
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));

// wait for the scroll height to change
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  .until(drv -> !drv.executeScript(JS_GET_INNER_HEIGHT).equals(innerHeight));

// scroll to the bottom
driver.executeScript(JS_SCROLL_BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into these and hopefully come back with an update.

Comment: The issue was actually with the next part of code that I didn't post, but your solution also makes sense for what I thought was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is timeOut that you specified is too low.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 1);
```

Keep it as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
```

This allows the method to `wait Up to 10 seconds` to check the condition, before throwing exception.

From Selenium Docs:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

> This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if
>   it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. WebDriverWait
>   by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it
>   returns successfully. A successful return value for the
>   ExpectedCondition function type is a Boolean value of true, or a
>   non-null object.

References:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: That didn't solve it, my issue is that I want to make sure my screen is resized before the scrolling occurs. Increasing the timeout only increases the amount of time allowed for the resizing to finish, and I am not getting any TimeoutExceptions so I don't think that's the issue. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: what exactly happening?  the browser is resized, but the condition did not return "True"? Or Condition returned "True" before the browser resized? please clarify

Comment: The condition returns true, which is correct. But I thought that by adding that condition check, I could ensure that scrolling occurs after resizing. This is not the case as sometimes, the scrolling is occuring before the resizing.

Comment: it means that height value you passed is matching to the current window height value, before resizing. please check the values you are passing.

Comment: please refer link http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition, different ways for writing ExpectedCondition

Comment: write some print statements in the apply method, like print height values to check how many times the method is getting executed. Keep print and observe the behaviour